# Pagination on products page

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, product-list

I need to show products pagination in the file `template\catalog\product\list.phtml`. How can I do it? Probably I need to edit `catalog.xml` but what to change I don't know.

Comment: template\catalog\product\list.phtml is a category page and by default pagination is present in this page.

Comment: @AnshuMishra, well `$this->getpagerhtml()` is accesible in `\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml`, but in the `list.phtml` it shows nothing.

Comment: Are you not getting only pagination or whole pagination block (containing product listing styles, pagination and sorting dropdown) ?

Comment: @AnshuMishra, I get the it the `toolbar.phtml`, but I need the in `list.phtml`. If I write the pager functions in `list.phtml` then they show nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->getPagerHtml()` in `catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml` means you are trying to call `getPagerHtml()` method of class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` 
whereas `$this->getPagerHtml()` in `catalog/product/list.phtml` means you are trying to call `getPagerHtml()` method of class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` where it is not present.
If you want to call `$this->getPagerHtml()` in `list.phtml` then first you need to create object of class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` in list.phtml 

Example :

> $object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar(); 
>   $object->getPagerHtml();

Comment: The class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Product_List_Toolbar` doesn't exists in `catalog/product/list.phtml` :(

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar(); I have modified my answer.

Comment: `$object->getPagerHtml()` echoes nothing. `print_r($object)` output is [http://pastebin.com/zxAR8Xw8](http://pastebin.com/zxAR8Xw8)

Comment: Also `$object->getCollection()` returns `NULL`. It should return the products collection, or not?

Comment: No, it will not return you the product collection. Rather it will provide html for pager block.

Comment: For more details and clarification you can go through Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar class.

Answer (score 2):

First get your product collection. For example, here the collection is `$merged_collection`. then apply the following code in the position where you want to place the pager and toolbar.

```
<?php  
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$pager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager');
$toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
$toolbar->setCollection($merged_collection);
$toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
echo $toolbar->toHtml();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wasnt able to find a way to get just the pager content, but I did find a way to show specific pieces of the toolbar, which contains the call to the pager.

***In toolbar.phtml***

Find the "sorter" div and wrap it like so:

```
<?php if (!$this->getHideSorter()) : ?>
*...sorter div stuff here...*
<?php endif; ?>
```

Similarly, find the "pager" div and wrap it like so:

```
<?php if (!$this->getHidePager()) : ?>
*...pager div stuff here...*
<?php endif; ?>
```

***In list.phtml***

You can add the pager like so:

```
<?php echo
$this->getToolbarBlock()->setHideSorter(true)->setHidePager(false)->toHtml();
?>
```

And you can add the sorter with this:

```
<?php echo 
$this->getToolbarBlock()->setHideSorter(false)->setHidePager(true)->toHtml();
?>
```

Or you could add both like this:

```
<?php echo 
$this->getToolbarBlock()->setHideSorter(false)->setHidePager(false)->toHtml();
?>
```

I would not have come to this solution without the help from another answer here on Stackexchange... Much props to @Marius (https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) for his answer here:

[How can I disable/remove the pager in toolbar above my product-grid?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5380/how-can-i-disable-remove-the-pager-in-toolbar-above-my-product-grid)

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 1.9 the only code that worked for me was the following:

```
$toolbarBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar');
$pagerBlock = $toolbarBlock->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

$pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($toolbarBlock->getAvailableLimit());

$pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
    ->setShowPerPage(false)
    ->setShowAmounts(false)
    ->setLimitVarName($toolbarBlock->getLimitVarName())
    ->setPageVarName($toolbarBlock->getPageVarName())
    ->setLimit($toolbarBlock->getLimit())
    ->setFrameLength(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame'))
    ->setJump(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip'))
    ->setCollection($_productCollection);

echo $pagerBlock->toHtml();
```