# Load pagination on list.phtml

Tags: category, product-list, pagination, list.phtml

i'm trying to create my first magento template and i'm facing problems to load the pagination toolbar.

My last try was using

```
$object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar();
echo $object->getPagerHtml();
```

This hint was taken from

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/pagination-on-products-page
```

But on my `catalog/product/list.phtml` doesn't show my pagination.
Maybe I'm missing something on XML layout?
PS.: Neither `toolbar.phtml` loads

Comment: You want to load it in custom template ?

Answer (score 1):

First check your theme layout file **catalog.xml**

`<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">`

is set in **catalog_category_default(Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)** and **Catalog Category (Anchor))** node,

If code not existing so add this code. you can copy it from base theme catalog.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please check below article it will help you to create pagination in your template file :

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/18/magento-collection-paging/