# Magento Product Detail Page Pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, pagination

In Magento Product Detail Page Pagination, I want to show **prev** **next** pagination in Magento 1. How I can do that?

Comment: Please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/pagination-on-products-page

Answer (score 0):

Please check this links

http://inchoo.net/magento/simple-helper-class-for-previous-next-products-in-magento/

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/listing-out-previousnext-products-in-magento-inchoo_prevnext-extension/

Check Free Extension : https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_Prevnext

I hope it'll help you.