# Unset magento toolbar-bottom in local.xml

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-list, toolbar

Is it possible to remove only the bottom toolbar of a category page using the local.xml file without editing the template files? I want to keep the top toolbar..

Maybe something along these lines?

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setHideToolbars"><value>1</value></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without editing the template files is not possible.
But [here is a possible solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5382/146) to hiding parts of the toolbar or splitting the toolbar in paging and sorting. One at the top and one at the bottom.

If you want to hide the full toolbar from the bottom, edit `catalog/product/list.phtml` and remove the lines

```
<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Or you can do it via css by setting `display:none` for the `.toolbar-bottom` class.

Comment: I have done this, however I am in specific interested in removing it with the local.xml file

Comment: I understood that. Unfortunately that's not possible AFAIK.